# How to select multiple row values in to a variable in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have written a script that defines variables.

One of the variables is defined like this.

```
SET @Yesterday = (SELECT SUM (ri.Sales_Quantity) 
                  FROM ReportTransactions AS RT     
                  LEFT JOIN ReportItems AS ri ON rt.Report_Transaction_ID = ri.Report_Transaction_ID    
                  LEFT JOIN MMGroups AS mmg ON ri.MMGroup2_ID = MMG.ID  
                  LEFT JOIN Locations AS L ON L.Location_ID = RT.Store_ID 
                  WHERE rt.Transaction_Date > DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) 
                    AND (NULL IS NULL OR rt.Store_ID = NULL)   
                    AND (rt.Training_Mode IS NULL OR rt.Training_Mode = 0)   
                    AND ri.Item_Voided = 0   
                    AND ri.Void_Type = 0
                    AND rt.Transaction_Type IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)   
                    AND ri.Item_Type IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 54, 55, 81, 84, 11, 12, 13, 22, 25, 27, 82) 
                  GROUP BY  
                      RT.Store_ID);
```

This however returns multiple values so cannot define the variable and throws an error.

I need all these rows for my report so how can I define them and retrieve the, what is the best practice?

Comment: Store them in a temporary table, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need table either `temporary` or `base` as because of you want multiple rows or columns :

```
SELECT RT.Store_ID, SUM (ri.Sales_Quantity) AS Sum_Qty INTO #table
FROM ReportTransactions AS RT LEFT JOIN 
     ReportItems AS ri 
     ON rt.Report_Transaction_ID = ri.Report_Transaction_ID LEFT JOIN 
     MMGroups AS mmg 
     ON ri.MMGroup2_ID = MMG.ID LEFT JOIN 
     Locations AS L 
     ON L.Location_ID = RT.Store_ID 
WHERE . . .     
GROUP BY RT.Store_ID;
```

however, Base table requires `INSERT INTO` statement with `SELECT` statement :

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2)
     SELECT . . . ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try a table variable.

```
DECLARE @Yesterday  Table
(
Sum_Qty  int
)
insert into @Yesterday
SELECT SUM (ri.Sales_Quantity) 
                  FROM ReportTransactions AS RT     
                  LEFT JOIN ReportItems AS ri ON rt.Report_Transaction_ID = ri.Report_Transaction_ID    
                  LEFT JOIN MMGroups AS mmg ON ri.MMGroup2_ID = MMG.ID  
                  LEFT JOIN Locations AS L ON L.Location_ID = RT.Store_ID 
                  WHERE rt.Transaction_Date > DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) 
                    AND (NULL IS NULL OR rt.Store_ID = NULL)   
                    AND (rt.Training_Mode IS NULL OR rt.Training_Mode = 0)   
                    AND ri.Item_Voided = 0   
                    AND ri.Void_Type = 0
                    AND rt.Transaction_Type IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)   
                    AND ri.Item_Type IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 54, 55, 81, 84, 11, 12, 13, 22, 25, 27, 82) 
                  GROUP BY  
                      RT.Store_ID
```